# Pad a struct so its size is a multiple of 16 bytes

Tags: c#, struct, padding, structlayout

I'm trying to have my C# struct match up some complex [padding and packing rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/dx-graphics-hlsl-packing-rules).

- Fields should be aligned on 4 byte boundaries.
- The entire struct should be a multiple of 16 bytes

Using the [StructLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute?view=net-6.0) attribute I can make sure that fields are aligned on 4 byte boundaries.

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=4)]
struct Foo
{
    float a;
    float b;
}
```

But looking at the other options for the StructLayout attribute I see no options for padding the struct to multiples of 16 bytes. Is there no option for that in C#?

The only option I see is manually set the right size, using the [Size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.size?view=net-6.0) property of the StructLayout attribute. But that seems brittle to me. As every time somebody adds a field to this struct they should take care not to forget to update the size.

Comment: Just as a workaround, you could potentially write a unit test to *detect* that the Size hasn't been manually set correctly, via reflection. So it would be slightly annoying, but not actually brittle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more searching, it indeed does look like I have to manually set the Size and FieldOffset to get to the right packing rules for Constant Buffers in DirectX/HLSL/C# interop code.

In my own project this is even a bit more complex. Since I use source generators to create these structs. But in the end I was able to figure it out. For those interested the source code can be found [here](https://github.com/roy-t/MiniEngine3/blob/bba5f678b4d035d810a7bd21135dd748b9a628b3/src/Generators/Mini.Engine.Content.Generators/HLSL/StructGenerator.cs#L51).